# splitting by certain value if doesn't match specific values -- javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this

I have a string and I want to split values of it by '=' into an array.

The problem is that some of the values could be '>=', and '<='

so far I've got this where I change it to something else before splitting and mapping them

```js
let s = "x=a&y=b&z=>=5";
let x = s.replace('>=', '**');

console.log(s.replace('>=', '**').split("=").map(x => x.includes('**') ? x.replace('**', '>=') : x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with one `split` by using the following regular expression:

`/(?<=[^>|<])=/`

Breaking this expression up we can look at each component:

- `[^>|<])=` - Essentially means match any character (excluding `<` and `>`)
  followed by an equals
- `(?<=` - Perform a positive look behind on the `[^>|<]`. Basically,
  if we didn't have this, we would match any_character_but_>_or_<
  followed by an equals, however, what we want to do is only match the
  `=` which has any_character_but_>_or_< before it, but not include
  that character in our match.

  Eg: without this, our expression would match the string "a=b" to give us "`a=`", however, we only want to match the `=` and not the 'a'. The positive look behind allows us to do this.

  See working example below:

```js
let str = "x=a&y=b&z=>=5";
let res = str.split(/(?<=[^>|<])=/);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @totalnoob I've update my answer with an explanation

Comment: @totalnoob see https://regexr.com/444es and try removing `?=<` and see what gets highlighted, this should help aid your understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

From [regexp-lookbehind](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind),

Regex for negative lookbehind assertion - `/(?<!.)/`

Here `.` is replaced by `>|<` as we need to ignore the cases where our text(`=`) is preceded by `>` or `<`. `/g` is used to consider all the matches e.g. `x>=y=a<=d` will be resulting in `[x>=y, a<=d]`

```js
let s = "x=a&y=b&z=c>=5";
console.log(s.split(/(?<!>|<)=/g));
```

Comment: Have a look at this - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind This is the syntax for negative lookbehind assertion `/(?<!.)/`. Here `.` is replaced by `>|<` as we need to ignore the cases where our text is preceded by `>` or `<`.